# Optimization for Normal maps with lots of wasted space?

Tags: optimization, normal-mapping, unreal-4

I'm working on level/character assets where I'm finding that I use only very little amounts of normal mapping on them, resulting in 2048x2048 textures that are mostly blue/purple. Is there any method to better optimize this, perhaps use one normal map for several assets?

Comment: By "2k textures", do you mean 2 kilobytes, 2000×2000px resolution or a quantity of two thousand counts of textures?

Comment: 2048x2048 resolution textures

Answer (score 5):

With any asset with UV coordinates, it's good practice to have parts that need more detail take up more area than parts that don't (usually, anyway). So you can have the UV coordinates for the detailed parts of your normal map scaled quite large, and the UVs for the less detailed parts scaled quite small.

You can also have two different sets of UV coordinates -- the first used to sample the diffuse texture and the second used to sample the normal map. The second UV set could be laid out to make more efficient use of the texture space based on what needs more detail.

Comment: In other words you suggest 2 sets of UV coordinates, one for diffuse and another for normals, right?

Comment: Exactly. There's no need for normal and diffuse textures to share the same UV sets, except convenience in creation.

Comment: You may want to put that clarification into your answer.

Comment: I thought "second uv set just for the normal map" made that clear, but I can be blind to my own explanations. I'll clarify my answer now, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, additionally would it make any sense for assets  with an extra set of uv coordinates (for normals) to share one texture map? Or would that be problematic?

Comment: It might! That'd be something you decide on a case by case basis. Leaf details might suit a variety of props, for example, but facial details generated for a specific low-poly character from a high-poly mesh would be harder to re-use. Test out lower resolutions. If you space things efficiently, you might get all the detail you need out of 1024x1024 or even 512x512 normal maps, which'll give you much more room in your memory budget without having to bend over backwards to share normal maps that don't naturally lend themselves to it. I hope that makes sense :)